# Best practice for OOP style loading of nested objects from a YAML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file that describes the content of a text game. It contains the data required to populate many nested objects. These are scenes, actions, outcomes and state updates. A scene contains many actions, an action has many possible outcomes and an outcome can cause many states to update.

I have defined classes for each of these entities, but I am not sure of the best way to create them from an object oriented perspective. Should I be creating everything in one big nested set of for loops (say for example in the init of the game) or should I be passing down the data to the lower level classes and parsing it piece by piece?

With the former approach I feel like the construction of the objects and their relationships would be easier to understand. However, with the latter, I feel it would be easier to write unit tests.

I am loading it using a safe PyYAML loader, so tagging as particular python objects is not feasible.

Please give reasons for and against each approach, or other alternatives.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a method like `fromYaml` to each class, and having them call each other as necessary, if you can do it without breaking encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although "tagging as particular python objects is not feasable", it
**is** feasible to tag them with explicit tags, even within the
restrictions of a safe loader. This doesn't make it unsafe to load
your YAML file, unless the objects created from those tags have unsafe
side-effects on initiation.

Using tags also allows you to dump (and load) the data-structure you
have in memory even if you have at some point in your development
references from more than one object to one specific other object or
when you have objects with (indirect) references to itself. These will
be dumped using anchors and aliases, and it is non-trivial to resolve
these things yourself when dumping without using tags, as you would
need to keep track of already dumped objects.

Unittest for individual can easily be written. Normally the only thing you
have to make sure is that you can create a scene without actions, then you can 
test everything for the scene that doesn't involve actions, etc.

PyYAML can parse all of the YAML 1.1 specification, but cannot load
all of that spec. Additionally YAML 1.2 has been out for ten years now.
Neither might be a restriction for your program, but I do recommend to 
use `ruamel.yaml`, which does not have these problems 
(disclaimer: I am the author of that package). How to dump/load classes
with `ruamel.yaml` is described [here](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html)

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

data_file = Path('data.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

@yaml.register_class
class Scene:
    def __init__(self, sc_parm, actions):
       self.sc_parm = sc_parm
       self.actions = actions

@yaml.register_class
class Action:
    def __init__(self, ac_parm1, ac_parm2):
        self.ac_parm1 = ac_parm2
        self.ac_parm2 = ac_parm2


shared_action = Action('south', 1)

data = [
    Scene('sc1_parm_val', []), 
    Scene('sc2_parm_val', [Action('north', 3), shared_action]),
    Scene('sc3_parm_val', [shared_action, Action('west', 2)]),
]

yaml.dump(data, data_file)

print(data_file.read_text(), end='')
print('=+'*30)
d2 = yaml.load(data_file)

for d in d2:
    print(d.sc_parm, d.actions)
```

which gives:

```
- !Scene
  actions: []
  sc_parm: sc1_parm_val
- !Scene
  actions:
  - !Action {ac_parm1: 3, ac_parm2: 3}
  - &id001 !Action {ac_parm1: 1, ac_parm2: 1}
  sc_parm: sc2_parm_val
- !Scene
  actions:
  - *id001
  - !Action {ac_parm1: 2, ac_parm2: 2}
  sc_parm: sc3_parm_val
=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
sc1_parm_val []
sc2_parm_val [<__main__.Action object at 0x7f009be56f28>, <__main__.Action object at 0x7f009be56fd0>]
sc3_parm_val [<__main__.Action object at 0x7f009be56fd0>, <__main__.Action object at 0x7f009be56e48>]
```

As you can see from the IDs of the `Action` objects, the second action
of the second scene is again the same as the first action of the last
scene (the original `shared_action`)

Make sure, that if you decide to make your own `from_yaml` (instead of
relying on the default you get by registering), e.g. in order to limit
the attributes that get dumped, that you use the two step process of
creating your objects as this is necessary to allow for recursive data
structures in your tree. You might not need this right away, but it is
rather easy to do and e.g. described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51827378/1307905) for the
round-trip loader (a safe-loader that can preserve comments, quoting
styles, alias names etc when loading then dumping YAML).

Comment: Thank you for the highly detailed response. Please could you clarify a couple of things for me. I do need to make my own from_yaml function, however, I'm slightly confused by how it works. Could you please point me to any resources that give examples of creating objects using custom from_yaml class methods? I checked/searched the documentation but couldn't find very much.

Comment: The documentation only has a from_yaml that uses a scalar. What you need to do is look at the second link I provided in my answer, [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51827378/1307905) shows a `from_yaml`, the only thing is that it uses the round-trip loader for the safe-loader you should replace `CommentedMap()` with `dict()`