# Why is ruamel.yaml giving me invalid yaml when loading from custom classes?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I was trying out the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806918/how-to-create-a-custom-yaml-mapping-dumper-for-ruamel-yaml/51827378#51827378) question. And found some issues with the dumper, especially when adding some comments around the YAML tags.

```py
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap
import io

class Hero:
    yaml_tag = '!Hero'
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, data):
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, {'name': data.name, 'age': data.age})

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        data = CommentedMap()
        constructor.construct_mapping(node, data, deep=True)
        return cls(**data)

yaml = YAML()
yaml.register_class(Hero)

## Test case
in_str = '''\
people:
    # Hello
    - !Hero
        name: Mary
        age: 20
    - !Hero
        name: Jane
        age: 24
name: friends
'''

f = io.StringIO()

data = yaml.load(in_str)
yaml.dump(data, f)
print(f.getvalue())
```

This outputs:

```yaml
people:
    # Hello
- !Hero name: Mary
  age: 20
- !Hero
  name: Jane
  age: 24
name: friends
```

Which is invalid YAML, as the name `Mary` is in the same line of the `!Hero` tag.

In fact, if you try to load it again with `yaml.load(f.getvalue())` gives the following error:

```
ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: expected a mapping node, but found scalar
  in "<unicode string>", line 3, column 3:
    - !Hero name: Mary
      ^ (line: 3)
```

Comment: That you cannot load the resulting YAML is because your `from_yaml()` assumes a node parameter to be a `MappingNode`, that doesn't necessarily make the YAML invalid and in this case it is valid (but admittedly not what should have been dumped, nor what you want).

Answer (score 1):

Your output is valid YAML, it just doesn't load with the registered class Hero as is.

What is the real problem is that you have a comment between your key `people` and it's value
which is not handled properly, and causes the dumping for the first sequence element
to differ from your second sequence element (which loads fine even with your code):

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap

class Hero:
    yaml_tag = '!Hero'
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, data):
        return representer.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, {'name': data.name, 'age': data.age})

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        data = CommentedMap()
        constructor.construct_mapping(node, data, deep=True)
        return cls(**data)

yaml = YAML()
yaml.register_class(Hero)

## Test case
in_str = '''\
# Hello 1
people:
    - !Hero
        name: Mary  # Hello 2
        age: 20
    - !Hero
        name: Jane
        age: 24
name: friends
'''


data = yaml.load(in_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# Hello 1
people:
- !Hero
  name: Mary
  age: 20
- !Hero
  name: Jane
  age: 24
name: friends
```

Doing your own class registering was necesssary in the time the answer you refer to was written.
Nowadays ruamel.yaml in round-trip mode loads and dumps most tagged elements without needing to
register any class ( with the known exception of tagged `null` values).

My strong recommendation is not to do any registering or use your own Hero class to roundtrip a YAML document.
That doesn't solve the
comment-between-key-and-value issue, but at least preserves the `# Hello 2` eol comment.
Your code (nor the example) probably doesn't deal with (self-) recursive data structures as is,
something also transparently handled by not registering code.

Adjusting your `to_yaml` to do both of that is of course possible but non-trivial.